# Large items in Combo Box won't open

Tags: html

In Safari for windows when you fill a drop down box with a lot of items it will open the first time you mouse down. The second time it won't open.

Works fine in Safari for Mac,Firefox,Chrome and IE.

Is there a limitation with Safari for Windows?

Comment: Seems like a bug - how many items?

Comment: Please post some code or a demo fiddle.